# Get another page's content in a variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

Is there a way to set a javascript variable as the content of another HTML page?

I tried:

`var X = $(http://www.website.com/home).html()`

but it didn't return anything.... Even tho it explains the idea... so... can anyone tell me how to do so please? Also the content of a certain `id` or `class` in that website, something like:

`var X=$(http://www.website.com/home "#id").html()`

It would really help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have permission for the other site to allow cross-origin stuff?

Comment: yes, i do, they're all in my domain

Comment: If the code is authentic, you have a syntax error (you should quote the URL). Please use the dev console to catch these.

Comment: Code is not authentic... I tried some other variants and I asked becouse I couldn't find it out, but it was to give the idea, since maybe the text didn't explain enough

Comment: Look at `$.get` and its relatives, then. Also, read up about the same-origin policy

Comment: i can't find an explanation on how $.get works on jQuery, can you link me to a good website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for this:

```
$.get('otherPage.html').then(function(responseData) {
  //responseData is the contents of the other page. Do whatever you want with it.
  $('#someElem').append(responseData);
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/8l95Kr9fchYBDcD3taMJ?p=preview)**

`$.get()` is a shorthand method for jQuery's `$.ajax()`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/