# Get content from another page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to load divs from page 2 into page 1 with JavaScript.

Page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content2"> this is content2</div>
<div id="content3"> this is content3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get and use the id content2 from page2 to create a div into page1 with the content of that div, after link was clicked and deleted, and do the same with content3, content4 and successively.

Page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content1"> this is content1</div>
<a href="#"> get content</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then would be like that.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content1"> this is content1</div>
<div>this is content2</div>
<div>this is content3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new in JavaScript and i have no ideia how to do that. If someone can help. Thanks.

Edited: I wanted a way to do it only with javascript and without jquery if that's really possible. I want my project working offline and I can't do that with jquery, because it doesn't work. I've downloaded jquery plugin and pasted it in my directory, but, didn't work, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get another page's content in a variable with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927573/get-another-pages-content-in-a-variable-with-ajax)

Comment: Look into forms and posting.  Then look into jQuery `.post()` or `AJAX` methods.  These should help you get started ...

Comment: If one of the pages is in an iframe, you can directly [access its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript) from the other page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of JavaScript, jQuery, and AJAX to accomplish this.

First, include the jQuery library:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Then write a JavaScript function similar to this one which will replace your div element's html content with the Page2.html file:

```js
var loadNewContent = function {
  $.ajax("Page2.html", {
    success: function(response) {
      $("#content2").html(response);
    }
  }); 
};
```

And then you would need some 'trigger' to run this function such as this:

```js
$("#content2").on('click', loadNewContent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small library called ViaJS using javascript & jquery. It basically lets you load content (like a div) from a source to the page. Check it out.

[Via is a small library that allows you to load content on to a page dynamically](https://github.com/abdi0987/ViaJS)