# DOM parsing page to extract table data

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way with a Javascript to load a page and parse it to extract data from a table and write it to a tsv file?
Thank you

Comment: Yes. There is a way.

Comment: Ok nice answer... I tought to get the page with wget or curl and redirect the output to a file. Then parse with a c# or python or whatever else. I would like ti know whether pure JavaScript i can parse the page. Thank you

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229043/load-page-content-to-variable), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866073/get-entire-content-of-page) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927573/get-another-pages-content-in-a-variable-with-ajax). They might help